# How to remove this border from tooltipdialog that shows up on mouse click?

Tags: dojo

Whenever I click inside a tooltipdialog, this border shows up around it.

[image]

Is there an easy way to remove this?

**EDIT:**  After trying in different browsers, it seems to affect only Chrome, the outline doesn't appear in Firefox or IE.

Comment: I think you can use `outline:none` in CSS to avoid it. Can you make a snippet or a jsfiddle so we can give a clear answer ?

Comment: @ben I couldn't get the tootlip working in jsfiddle on my own but I found this example which basically has the same behavior - also try it in Chrome and you will see it, the outline doesn't appear in Firefox or IE http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/3232e/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faces the similar issue when i started working on Dojo. To fix this basically you need to add the following css for dijit's `dijitTooltipDialog` class

```
.dijitTooltipDialog {
    outline : none
}
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mpLhk29k/) for example.